# Bootstrap buttons with glyphicons show different results

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've written some code that makes a menu. I've used bootstrap to manage this. 
My problem is they show different behaviour on different computers:

This is the html code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="createStoryBox"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" style="display: inline-block"></span><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"style="display: inline-block"> {{ _('Create story') }}</span></button>
        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createEventModal" style="display: inline-block" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> {{ _('Create event') }}</span></button>
</div>
```

[Behviour 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dh3O.jpg)
[Behaviour 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qO68.png)

Comment: Is it possible that the browser that is displaying `Behavior 2` is zoomed in? Is it the same resolution as the computer used for `Behavior 1`?

Comment: Maybe the screen size/resolution is different ?

Comment: May be the screen resolutions are different.

Comment: I tested the zooming, but this has no effect to the behaviour. And yes, we have used different resolutions. But isn't the point of bootstrap that it works on different devices?

Comment: have you tried whether this happens too when using font awesome instead? also try removing all your custom styles. they might break the expected behaviour

Comment: Can you be more specific about the different behaviours ? E.g. are both computers using the same browser with the same version, is there a compatibility mode enabled, is there an accessibility mode enabled, ...

Comment: Same browser, same os.. only difference between the two computers are the resolutions.